# Why Spark evaluator has avgMetrics attributes if it only returns 1 value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using [MulticlassClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html) to retrieve some metrics like F1-Score or accuracy in a Cross Validation in PySpark:

```py
cross_result = CrossValidator(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(),
                              estimatorParamMaps=ParamGridBuilder().build(),
                              evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName='f1'),
                              numFolds=5,
                              parallelism=-1)

f1_score = cross_result.avgMetrics[0]
```

Now, my question is: why is `avgMetrics` a list if it only has one value? Doesn't It should be a scalar value? Am I missing something about this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the source code, I realized that `avgMetrics` is a list with the average of all the cross-validation folds of the metric for each parameter defined in `ParamGrid`. So:

```py
dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(Vectors.dense([0.0]), 0.0),
     (Vectors.dense([0.6]), 1.0),
     (Vectors.dense([1.0]), 1.0)] * 10,
    ["features", "label"])
lr = LogisticRegression()

# Note that there are three values for maxIter: 0, 1 and 5
grid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.maxIter, [0, 1, 5]).build()
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName='accuracy')
cv = CrossValidator(
    estimator=lr,
    estimatorParamMaps=grid,
    evaluator=evaluator,
    parallelism=2
)
cvModel = cv.fit(dataset)

cvModel.avgMetrics[0] # Average accuracy for maxIter = 0
cvModel.avgMetrics[1] # Average accuracy for maxIter = 1
cvModel.avgMetrics[2] # Average accuracy for maxIter = 5
```